# How to make customize Large Navigation bar like iOS 11 "News App" do so?

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios11

Small title
[image]

Large Title
[image]

I wanna make a navigation bar behave like the NEWS App of Apple. 
I know how to make large title of the bar.
But I have no idea for the right navigation bar item.
Please give me some advices.

Is there any delegate to know the large title is appearing?
How to add a bar item next to the large title but disappear when it turns back to small? (Something just like APP Store "APP" tab's navigation bar)

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 11, a new property has been added to `UINavigationBar`i.e. `prefersLargeTitles`

Just add, following line in `viewDidLoad()`

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Or you can set it to true in Interface Builder as well.

**NOTE :** In some cases it is not working if you set it from IB.

Comment: Yes, I know how to set large title.

Comment: But how to set rightbarbutton follow as large title?

Comment: like my second image

Comment: Okay give me some time

Comment: and I want to know how to add custom view into largeTitleView? Like "APP" tab's navigationBar of AppStore on iPhone devices

Comment: Let me know if you get it as two line large title in tab bar